# How do you make the Minecraft full screen window full screen on Windows 10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

Does anyone know how to make Minecraft run in full screen mode?

My display is set to 1920 x 1080, and the game was able to run full screen a while ago, but, I forget what the workaround was - any ideas? I haven't updated my graphics drivers in ages, so, it wasn't a driver update that broke things.

Pressing F11 enters "full screen mode" but this only occupies a subset of the window.

I set the resolution to 1920 x 1080 in the launch options, but the window is still 1024 x 768 or something - I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried:

- Toggling "Fullscreen" in the Video Settings
- Setting a resolution of 1920x1080 in the "Full Screen Mode" setting in the Video Settings menu
- Settting a resolution of 1920 x 1080 in the launch options
- Disabling Optifine and repeating the above
- Disabling high DPI optimizations for javaw.exe
- Pressing F11 to enter full screen with "Fullscreen" set to "On" or "Off"
- Pressing ALT + Enter

I have Optifine 1.12 installed, but disabling Optifine doesn't fix this.

This worked a few weeks ago, but, like a fool, I do not recall how I managed to get full screen mode to take up the full screen.

[image]
[image]

Comment: i have the same problem but on windows 8 -_-

Comment: can i ask what your graphics card is, and if its drivers are updated?

Comment: You could try using borderless gaming to make the minecraft window look exactly like fullscreen (only noticable difference would be multi monitor mouse capturing).

Comment: have you tried shifting the window around by pressing win key+shift+arrow keys? this sometimes causes windows to resize to the current monitor (even in fullscreen). also, try updating your graphics drivers, updating drivers for intel graphics has so far fixed a lot of my problems that happened out of nowhere, dunno what it is with intel drivers but yeah

Comment: This still could be a problem with the driver because maybe the newer versions of Minecraft do not support that driver version.

Comment: I think i have seen this before, however not sure what you are seeing might be due to the same reason. After server i used to play on changed fronm 1.13 to 1.14. I upgraded the client and forge/schematica/journeymap mods, the default gfx adapter somehow changed from my nvidia gfx(dedicated) to IntelHD(onboard), still not sure how as no nvidia gfx driver was updated. i started seeing the same window issues you describe, i too removed/installed optifine, however eventually figured out the launcher you can rightclick and launch with 'nvidia dedicated gfx' and the issues were gone.

Comment: Can you try going fullscreen on a vanilla installation? Maybe some of the mods you (seem to) use are interfering?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the maximize button (square, just in case anyone doesn't know what it is,) but I assume you may have tried that. You could drag the window to resize it. If pressing F11 doesn't enter fullscreen, or makes it borderless, perhaps a reinstallation for Java or Minecraft could be done. Considering you've done these, look into Mojang/Minecraft official support. Considering that they made the game, they'd be the most efficient choice of support for your issue at the [Minecraft Help Page](https://help.minecraft.net)